# Change Xenserver 6.5 MTU

Tags: networking, xen, xenserver, nic, mtu

How do I go about change the **MTU setting** for my management interface in **xenserver 6.5**? Right now its set to the default 1500 but I want to increase it to 9000.

For my setup I have **2 nics on each host** - 1 nic provides access to our data network and nic 2 communicates with our san so we can run backups and setup iscsi connections to run/store VM's.

It doesn't seem like I can do this through **xencenter** and I haven't found any **CLI commands** that work either. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/596858/xenserver-6-2-changing-mtu This is a related question and the answers there will help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you can do this from XenCenter (and the CLI) but you have to set the MTU before using the interface.

For example, on my servers, if I go to Networking tab, select the interface used for my Management interface in the Networks area, under Network Settings, it states:

> The network's MTU cannot be changed as it is in use as the management interface 'Management').

Comment: I see that but how do I go about changing it since the management network is always in use? Is it possible to shutdown the hosts not being used and then make the change?